# Use iterator to check an ascending order (row major order) arraylist of a specific object with a number id?

Tags: java, iterator

I have a class that implement an iterator, each object in this class has an id which refers a number.

```
public class Shelf extends Observable implements Iterable<Book>{
       final static int NumRow = 10;
       final static int NumCol = 10;
       Book[][] books = new Book[NumRow][NumCol];

       # Here is the code for Iterator<Book> iterator();
```

I have already implement the iterator with hasNext, and Next methods

```
class Book implement Comparable<Book>{
      private int id
      public int getId() {return id;}
```

How can I check if the entire arraylist is in ascending order by each object's id? 
This is what I wrote

```
boolean ascending order(){
       boolean check = true;
       Iterator<Book> iter = shelf.iterator();
       while (iter.hasNext()){ \\How can I wrote here?
       }

       return check;
```

How can I compare the current id with the next id?

Comment: Share some code please

Answer (score 0):

You can store the value of the `id` and check at the next element, then change the value of `previous`

```
private static boolean isOrdered() {
    Iterator<Book> ite = shelf.iterator();
    int previousId = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    while (ite.hasNext()) {
        Book next = ite.next();
        if (next.getId() < previousId) {
            return false;
        }
        previousId = next.getId();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: what if the id start with 5?

Comment: @jarins i updated to match your problem, check it out and tell me

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code.

```
    public boolean checkAscendingSort(List<Book> books){
        for(int i=1; i<books.size(); i++){
            if(books.get(i).getId() < books.get(i-1).getId()){
              return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Of course, there are several ways to implement this feature.

Comment: I hope this helps，even my English is very bad.